# google script = if cell not empty then run script on the non empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script

im trying to solved this script,
i want to run ".splitTextToColumns" only for cells that not empty

```
function doget(e) {

    var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadid");
  var CONTENT = FILE.getSheetByName("orders");
  var A1 = CONTENT.getRange("b:b");
  A1.createTextFinder("מספר הזמנה:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("שם המזמין:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("טלפון:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("אימייל:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("תאריך ההזמנה:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("פירוט ההזמנה:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("שם המסעדה:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("סכום:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("אמצעי תשלום:").replaceAllWith(",");
  A1.createTextFinder("מזומן").replaceAllWith("מזומן,");
  A1.createTextFinder("אשראי").replaceAllWith("אשראי,");

  A1 .splitTextToColumns (", "); 
}
```

Comment: Please English only

Comment: @Cooper Post is in English. Only the replacement characters are Unicode.

Comment: Was there a error thrown?

Comment: code is not in English

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is contiguous, no intervening blank lines, you can used the `Range.getDataRegion()` method to get the rows containing values.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("orders");
    let range = sheet.getRange("B1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    range.splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Range.getDataRegion()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion(Dimension))
- [Range.splitTextToColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#splitTextToColumns(TextToColumnsDelimiter))

Comment: I TRYED TO ADD THE CODE AND GET ERROR    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null]

Comment: I CHANGED TO FILE  AND NOW WORK-  let sheet = FILE.getSheetByName("orders"); THANKS YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I hope this resolves your issue.  If so please mark it as the answer to help other with similar situation find a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: when i have rows that splited. and new row that need to split. when the script run the new rows splite but the rows that already splited delete!

Comment: That's because `splitTextToColumns()` create a 2D array.  So let say you run it once and it fills in the spreadsheet columns with the split values.  If I now replace only row 1 with "1,2,3"  it will construct a 2D array [[1,2,3],[4,"",""],[5,"",""]...] overwriting all the values in row 2 and beyond in column 2 and 3 with blanks.

Comment: im beginer, and didnt understand what i need to change